# Create instance from a variable

Tags: php, oop

I want to do this:

```
private static function parserLib() {
    return USE_XML ? 'XmlParser' : 'IdfParser';
}

static function create($arr = []) {
    return new ${self::parserLib()}($arr);
}
```

I've tried with this:

```
 new ${'XmlParser'}($test);
```

Don't work.

This works:

```
 $var = 'XmlParser';
 new $var($test);
```

Why is not possible to use the `{}` to use the value retrieved from a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$var = 'XmlParser';
new $var($test);
```

You define variable **$var** and used it **value** to instance class.

```
new ${'XmlParser'}($test);
```

${'XmlParser'} is means **get value of variable XmlParser**, but you have not such variable.

You try get value of undefined variable and in the result got such error "PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: XmlParser".

If you define variable XmlParser it will be works

```
class XmlParser {}
$XmlParser = 'XmlParser';
new ${'XmlParser'}($test);
```

Also please read about php [string complex syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)